# How can I draw, on an Android MapView, rectangles that automatically re-size when the user zooms in and out?

Tags: android, android-mapview

My Android application has a MapView. I want to divide that MapView into a grid according to latitude and longitude, and shade the different cells of that grid different colors based upon a certain criteria. What's the simplest way to do this?

I could create semi-transparent, solid-color PNG Drawable rectangular images and put them in an ItemizedOverlay centered on the central points of the cells, but then the rectangles would grow and shrink as the user zoomed in and out on the map. I could extend MapView and override the zoom functions so that the rectangles got re-sized when the user zoomed, but that seems really complicated for something that should be simple! Please tell me a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg19804.html

The solutions is to extend Overlay, not MapView. And I don't have to use ItemizedOverlays or PNG Drawables, which is a relief, because I hate those things.

Comment: Hi Dan, do you get an overlay which changes size along with the zooming in and out of the map? Is your overlay drawn with GPS coordinates to define the borders, instead of an image? Thanks for your help.